# Override home button behaviour

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-homebutton

I am working on an app and i want it to be such that when the user presses home then nothing should happen. Is it possible to accomplish that? If that is not possible then is it possible that some other action is performed when hone is pressed. the whole idea is user should not leave the app directly from any screen.

update:can someone tell me how to define my app as launcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant make it work as you want, but you can disable it

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

and you can tell user that home button is disabled:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,"Home button is disabled",1);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL,0,0);
        toast.show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
}
```

Comment: i am getting an error that window manager cannot be set to a variable.what is that?
got it

Comment: Thanks a ton. It is working flwalessly on emulator. really I appreciate it very much.

Comment: Fortunately, this security hole has been closed in newer versions of Android.

Comment: Its not a security hole. How can you say that? Its very useful for the app I am making.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot. Whenever Home button is pressed, the framework will always throw you back on android's home screen. Sorry, you are out of luck.  :)

Comment: I have got it working following the above code. It works great on emulator as well as my device.

Answer (score 1):

> I am working on an app and i want it to be such that when the user presses home then nothing should happen. Is it possible to accomplish that?

Make your app be the home screen. The user can still remove your app by rebooting in safe mode.

Comment: what is safe mode? never heard about it at all.

Comment: @VyprNoch: http://androinica.com/2010/08/how-to-activate-android%E2%80%99s-safe-mode-to-get-out-of-a-force-close-loop/ and many other articles on this subject can be found via the search engine of your choice.

Comment: is it possible to make my app homescreen as you said? please can you tell me code or how to do it?

Comment: @VyprNoch: There is a Home sample app in your SDK. Mostly, you add category `HOME` to the `<intent-filter>` for the activity that is to be the home screen.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sadly the project would be dropped due to the functionality problem in android. BTW i learned a lot about android.